# Classic elevator combinatoric problem tangential question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

There's classic elevator problem that has been asked here before many times. 5 people got on an elevator that has 5 stops, assuming they all get off at random, what are the odds they all get off at different stops.

This is easy enough to answer:  $ 5! / 5^5 $ (I've verified the answer by googling)

My question is an offshoot. **does the number 25, derived by taking 5 people * 5 floors meaning anything in  this question?** When I initially started to answer this question, I thought the denominator would originally be 25. Because each of the 5 people has 5 choices, so person A can get off any of the floors from  {1,2,3,4,5} same for person B - E. So I thought it would 5 + 5 +5 +5 +5 = 25

Once I fiddled around with it I realized it's not, but I'm trying to figure out does the number represent anything in this problem? If anything?

Sometimes you get the classic question where a person has a choice of 3 soups and 2 breads, and of course there are $ 3 * 2 = 6 $ possible choices. I'm trying to understand if similar logic of what $ 5 people * 5 floors = 25 $ means here, if anything?

I know this is a weird question, but I'm trying to make sure I understand combinatorics and permutations properly.

Maybe if I phrase my question differently:

$5 ^ 5$ represents all possible options if any of the 5 people can get off any floor

$5!$ represents all possible options if all 5 people must get off on different floors

Does $ 5 * 5 $ represent or mean anything at all? I feel like it represents some limited case, but I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$5$ people each have $5$ different choices.

So, the question is, is the enumeration of the total number of choices accurately represented by

$$(5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5) ~~~\text{or}~~~ (5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5) ~?$$

Suppose that instead of $5$ people, you had $2$ people. 
Suppose that instead of $5$ choices for each person, you had $3$ choices for each person.

For $~a \in \{1,2\}, ~b \in \{1,2,3\}$ 
let the expression $[a,b]$ represent that Person-$a$ has made Choice-$b$.

Then the enumeration here would be:

$[1,1],[2,1]$ 
$[1,1],[2,2]$ 
$[1,1],[2,3]$

$[1,2],[2,1]$ 
$[1,2],[2,2]$ 
$[1,2],[2,3]$

$[1,3],[2,1]$ 
$[1,3],[2,2]$ 
$[1,3],[2,3]$

So, you have $(2)$ people. 
Each person has $(3)$ choices. 
So, the enumeration is

$$(3 \times 3) ~: ~(2) ~\text{factors}.$$

This analogizes to having $(5)$ people. 
Each person having $(5)$ choices. 
The enumeration being

$$(5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5) ~: ~(5)~\text{factors}.$$

Comment: Ok, if I can flip the question a bit. Let's say I said, pick a person at random, and assign them a floor at random. You pick a random person with probability 1/5, and the floor with proability 1/5. = 1/25. Doesn't this suggest there's 25 options? Btw to be totally clear I 100% accept that 5! is the right answer, but I'm juts having issues understanding what the 25 represents if anything at all

Comment: @Jackson Assuming that you are only selecting one person, and assuming that there are only $5$ floors to choose from, there are $(5 \times 5) = 25$ different results that could occur from this operation.  That is, you could select any one of $5$ people and for whichever person that you selected, you could assign them to any one of $5$ different floors.

Comment: Also, the answer to the underlying probability problem is $$\frac{5!}{5^5}.$$  The denominator represents that $5$ people each have $5$ choices.  The numerator represents that (for example) once Person-1 has made his choice, then regardless of which choice Person-1 has made, Person-2 will have only $(4)$ choices, rather than $(5)$ choices.  Continuing in this way, the numerator becomes $$5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1.$$

Comment: Ok, thank you, this makes sense. Counting is surprisingly difficult, so many scenarios to keep in mind with each problem. I think there's something fundamental I'm missing. Hopefully doing more problems makes it sink in

Comment: @Jackson Yes, what you are missing is that when you take *any* Math course, you have to treat it like a *foreign* language.  That means that from page 1 on, you have to *go slow*, so that when you come to the first set of exercises, you be sure that you do each one, and that you are confident of your work.  $80\%$ of the learning occurs by doing the exercises.  The idea is to become *very fluent* in Chapter 1, before proceeding to Chapter 2.  Fluency means thinking in terms of the *foreign language*.

Comment: @Jackson If you find yourself in an *intellectual hole*, where you are in the middle of a course, and you are not totally fluent in all aspects of the course, up to that point, then you have a problem.  To the best of my knowledge, the only  remedy is to *start over*.  Open the book to page 1, and proceed as specified in my previous comment.